# Get the model instance from within a lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, nested-attributes

I have a nested form that, upon update, creates duplicate entries for all the nested attributes. In order to prevent this, I want to use the `reject_if` option for `accepts_nested_attributes`. The code might look something like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :implicants, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.is_a_duplicate? }
```

Unfortunately, `a` here is an ActionController::Parameter, not the instance of the class I'm working with. I tried this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :implicants, :reject_if => lambda { |a| self.is_a_duplicate?(a) }
```

But this results in a call to the class, as opposed to the instance. Is there any way refer to the instance from within a `reject_if` lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this isn't something that the `:reject_if` should have responsibility for. `:reject_if` is meant to reject groups of parameters for very obvious and basic reasons, such as not having a first name or an email filled in. If it's somewhat more complex then you should just do the validations on the model that is being created. And if you're consistently creating duplicates when you don't want to then you should go further up the chain and prevent these params from ending up in your controller at all by eg. fixing the views.

Comment: Solid advice. In the end, I wasn't able to fix this in the view (as I still needed to present the child elements so that users could edit and update them), but I was able to check for duplicates in a transaction.